# ConTeXt's best approximation to amsart

Tags: context

ConTeXt's wiki and manuals explain very well how to configure all imaginable aspects of your document, but they don't seem to explain how *not* to do it.  There ought to be a very simple way (an `\environment` or something) to produce a no-nonsense, sober-looking math paper/thesis.  (I should add, perhaps, that I would consider anything substantially different from the style used in traditional journals, even the standard LaTeX `article`, as somewhat extravagant for a math paper.)

So, what are the ConTeXt analogues of `\documentclass{amsart}` and `\usepackage{amsthm}`?

Comment: Short answer: None. Unlike LaTeX, it is not too difficult to create such class in ConTeXt. A few of them exist (e.g., for PracTeX Journal, for Tugboat, for MAPS journal, etc.) in the contributed modules or the core modules. But none for Math journals that I am aware of. Note that there are users who use ConTeXt to produce math articles: for a while I used something to mimic IEEE classes, Sanjoy Mahajan has typeset a physics book using ConTeXt; there a Dutch math journal that uses ConTeXt; but since arxiv does accept ConTeXt files, these styles are not public. Also check the mailing list.

Comment: @Aditya Why should arxiv's accepting ConTeXt files mean that the style files for a physics book and a Dutch maths journal are not public? I don't really see the connection either way but, if anything, I'd expect arxiv's accepting such files to encourage people to share style files rather than the reverse.

Comment: I phrased that badly. As a user, I usually don't make such files public because (in ConTeXt) it is usually takes the same amount of effort to create a new style than adapt someone else's style. So, I don't see the value in formally releasing my style files (note that there is an overhead wrt documentation, supporting new features, etc). If arxiv etc. accepted ConTeXt files, then it would have been possible to simply scan arxiv for a few samples; but they do not. The other thing is that there has been very little demand for such styles. If there is demand, users might think about releasing them